# How can I give my own names to colours in R?

Tags: r

I've got a series of charts to plot, and I'd like to use the colours from my company's branding for all of them. I have the hexadecimals for each, but rather than writing those out for every plot, I'd like to use colours' names eg `compplum`, `compyellow`, `compgreen` etc. How can I set

```
compplum = "#6C217E"
```

at the beginning of my script, so that later on I can just write `colour = "compplum"` instead of `colour = "#6C217E"`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not use variables to hold the hex values?

```
mycompanycol <- "#0FF0F0"
plot(rnorm(100), rnorm(100), col = mycompanycol)
```

Answer (score -1):

There are several color palettes available in R such as rainbow(), heat.colors(), terrain.colors(), and topo.colors(). We can visualize these  as 3D pie charts using the plotrix R package. so it depends the one u want to use